# Spline iOS Embending

Tags: swift, swiftui, spline

I am trying to embed spline.design into my SwiftUI app, and using the native code generated and simply copying and pasting it, I am getting:

```
spline scene file is in an unknown format
```

```
import SplineRuntime

struct Onboarding3DView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // fetching from cloud
        let url = URL(string: "https://build.spline.design/JHA7PO5Xk7h6trzn-wYc/scene.splineswift")!

        // // fetching from local
        // let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "scene", withExtension: "splineswift")!

        try? SplineView(sceneFileURL: url).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

That is my code, the project runs well, but instead of showing the 3D element the error,

Tested on iPhone 14 Pro Max

Answer (score 0):

Per the Spline documentation, this error means "The exported file is too old, the runtime is too old, or the file might have become corrupted."

Try re-exporting your file